# Sphere only turns red when it intersects the first sphere of an array

Tags: c++, opengl

I use the below code to color my reference sphere red whenever it intersects with another sphere:

```
for(i=0;i<numTriangles;i++) {
    if(DoSpheresIntersect(&ref,&triArray[i])) 
         c=RED;
    else 
         c=GREY;
    OpenGLDrawSphere(ref, c);
    OpenGLDrawSphere(triArray[i], c);
}
```

However, my reference sphere only turns red if it intersects the first member of `triArray[i]`, meaning `triArray[0]`. In all other cases it stays grey, regardless of whether or not it intersects the remaining members of `triArray[i]`. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Are you shure that `DoSpheresIntersect` is working as intended?

Comment: Yes. It merely returns 1 if collision is detected and 0 if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you draw your reference sphere inside the loop, you draw it multiple times, once for each other sphere you test against. Since you most likely have a depth buffer, only the first time you draw the reference sphere will result in visible rendering. So if it's red the first time through the loop (i.e. it intersects the first sphere), it will show as red. Otherwise, it will be grey.

You can change your logic to something like this:

```
Color refColor = GREY;
for (i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
    if (DoSpheresIntersect(&ref, &triArray[i])) {
        c = RED;
        refColor = RED;
    } else {
        c = GREY;
    }
    OpenGLDrawSphere(triArray[i], c);
}
OpenGLDrawSphere(ref, refColor);
```